# Dependency Injection and the Single Responsibility Principle in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

when working with DI and Constructor Injection one has a helpful indicator for violations of the SRP because the number of parameters of a constructor will increase to an amount we start to feel uneasy about. One tackles this by refactoring into sensibly tailored classes and by using façade services and similar approaches.

However, when it comes to MVVM and the view model in particular, I’m having a hard time to apply these rules. The view model by its nature has the responsibility of providing commands which when invoked do some UI logics and call into the business layer. I don’t want to start a discussion about where to place the business logic, let’s agree upon that it’s in separate classes.

Now imagine a simple scenario: We’ve got a window with a list of files. The user can add files, remove files and do some stuff with them as renaming and opening the containing folder. The window also asynchronously gathers and displays some metadata for the files in columns of the list. Furthermore the user can open a details view and trigger online help. All that can be done from a toolbar and a context menu. Ok let’s stop here with functionality. One straight forward way to cluster functionality could be:

- ViewModel (for the entire window, implementing commands for the
  mentioned functionality)

Dependencies of the view model:

- FileManipulation
- WindowsExplorerService (To open an explorer window
  to show the containing folder)
- OnlineHelp
- MetadataGatherer
- MessageService (To open up message boxes in order to show errors and
  the likes)
- DetailsService (Provides the UI to show details for known
  file formats)

That’s already 6 dependencies and it’s easy to raise the number by adding functionality which can be triggered from the toolbar. In my opinion the dependencies cannot be hidden behind sensible façade services since each of them covers quite a different area of functionality (Ok, we could argue about MetadataGatherer and FileManipulation).

I think that view models are special in the way that they encapsulate the forwarding of user actions to very different dependencies.
However, 6 or more dependencies make me feel uneasy and the respective constructor smells badly. Do I miss an important point? Any ideas of how to refactor a case like this in general?

Comment: Hello my friend. AFAIK, you are right, but there are some cases that you cannot apply these rules. There are classes like Services, Sockets, and etc. that handle a bunch of responsibilities and are not following SRP. I think it is better to refer you to www.yegor256.com he talks about these cases and how to resolve this situations

Comment: It all depends on how many abstraction levels you're willing to put. For instance, you could break the dependency with the OnlineHelp and the MessageService by using event aggregators (most MVVM frameworks provide the facilities for that): the concept is that the viewmodel send messages to say "the user is asking for help". At the other end, you have an OnlineHelpViewModel that listens to those messages and reacts appropriately. The pro is that you break the dependency between your ViewModel and the online-help feature. The con is that it makes your code that much harder to follow

Comment: There's almost nothing you can't break down into more abstraction layers. But it's always a trade-off, as you reduce coupling but increase the overall complexity. From there, it's the developer job to know where to set the cursor

Comment: Vahid, can you point to the specific postings on www.yegor256.com?

Comment: Kevin, you are right. I considered this kind of coupling but found it too cumbersome. You neither know if anyone ever "subscribed" to consume the requests. If I step back and ask myself what is wrong with the 5 or 6 parameters constructor I'd say it's the smell of a SRP violation. But that doesn't go away with the kind of decoupling you propose. It is just hidden because we'd no longer inject the dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

The solution here is to use composition. The master window needs to be a composition of elements, each of those will have their own view model and that view model will handle single responsibility. The master view model will orchestrate them. They can communicate with each other using the event bus. Nearly all popular MVVM frameworks (I know about Caliburn Micro and ReactiveUI) support this.

Comment: I'd been thinking about this and many times I'd agree. But if you've got this ten buttons toolbar, would you really create two view model just for the toolbar? The same for the context menu with 10 items?

Comment: @dotsven Why do you say "_two view model just for the toolbar_"? I mean which two? The "main" one and the "toolbar+buttons" one?

Comment: @dotsven If you have a toolbar with ten buttons, you could, conceptually, define a view model for each button. At least in WPF, `Button` derives from `FrameworkElement`, so has a `DataContext` property you can use for MVVM databinding. Each fine-grained view model should hardly need many dependencies, as it'd only need to react to a few well-defined events, such as `Click`. It's not that you _must_ decompose UIs like this, but since the question was how to decompose, then it'd be fair to say that WPF is extraordinarily (de)composable.

Comment: @aendeerei The "two" was nonsense. I should have written "multiple". One for each functional cluster in the toolbar. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Mark Seemann That's right. I think that is one of the best things about WPF. However isn't it quite over-complicated to actually decompose a toolbar like this? We'd have to introduce additional messaging between the view models of the toolbar and the one for the entire list or window. It's possible, alright - but for such a simple thing... I'd do that if there was for example a details view in the window. In that case I'd eagerly introduce a new view model for that area.

Comment: @dotsven _"isn't it quite over-complicated to actually decompose a toolbar like this?"_ I can't answer that; it depends on what the alternative is.